# Javascript - Removing a function from input tag

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, inline

I'm trying to revive a Chrome extension that's been useful to me in the past. I don't really know HTML or Javascript, but I do have a general idea about how it works. I know C so that helps to understand the syntax. 
So I've changed the manifest 2 key, and things that go along with it, but now have stopped at a problem I can't google my way out of. 
Because Chrome doesn't allow for inline scripts anymore I've had to link the .js scripts to the .html file, but not sure how to fix the following error message:

> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. popup.html:18

So the line in question is

```
<input type="text" value="" id="home_search_q" size="15" onKeyPress="checkEnter(event, this.value);" autofocus="true" />
```

The .html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SearchBox Toolbar</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/popup.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="logo">
<div id="logobtn" title="">
<img src="img/logo16.gif" id="logoimg">
</div>
</td>
<td id="query">
<input type="text" value="" id="home_search_q" size="15" onKeyPress="checkEnter(event, this.value);" autofocus="true" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I think the problem is that the argument is a function checkEnter which is not allowed, but I have no idea how I would change it into a script or bypass this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use inline event handlers.

Instead, call `addEventListener()` in an external script.